# Spring Batch- Refactoring @StepScope bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am facing an issue. When I am moving FlatFileItemReader and Step into separate configuration file it stopped working.

The actual issue is it is not able to get the jobParameters.

```
@Configuration
public class FileReader {


    @Bean("personFileReader")
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> personFileReader(@Value("#(jobParameters['customerFile']") FileSystemResource fileName) {

        System.out.println(
                String.format("fileName = %s", fileName));

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>().name("personItemReader").resource(fileName).fixedLength()
                .columns(getRange()).names(getNames()).targetType(Person.class).build();

    }
```

**Batch Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("personFileReader")
private FlatFileItemReader<Person> personFileReader;


@Bean
public Step step() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("chunkStep").<Person, Person>chunk(10).reader(personFileReader)
            .writer(dummyWriter).build();
```

}

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file [D:\Data\Study\spring-batch\batch-process\#(jobParameters['customerFile']]
```

I have no idea what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Value annotation seems to be incorrect

```
@Value("#(jobParameters['customerFile']")
```

Should be

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['customerFile']}")
```

Comment: Thanks.Good catch :)